# Android Studio: Not launching activity with edit text

Tags: java, android, emulation

I have a very basic application running that tells whether a definition is correct or not. The main activity only has a textView and an editText. When I try to run the emulator it says the app has stopped. Any Ideas as to what's wrong? Thanks in advance

Main Activity

```
package com.example.owner.epsilon;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_physics);

    final EditText answer =  (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.answer);
    String userAnswer = answer.getText().toString();

    if(userAnswer.contains("remain"+"force"+"constant"+"velocity")){
        System.out.print("Correct");
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("Incorrect");
    }


}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

XML file

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Newton's First Law"
        android:id="@+id/definitionTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/definitionTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="114dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Stack Trace:

```
Waiting for device.
Device connected: emulator-5554
Device emulator-5554 is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device emulator-5554 is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device is ready: emulator-5554
Target device: emulator-5554
Uploading file
    local path:        C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\Epsilon\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.owner.epsilon
Installing com.example.owner.epsilon
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r    "/data/local/tmp/com.example.owner.epsilon"
```

pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.owner.epsilon

```
Device disconnected: emulator-5554
Launching application:    com.example.owner.epsilon/com.example.owner.epsilon.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.example.owner.epsilon/com.example.owner.epsilon.MainActivity" -a  android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error: Adb refused a command
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Post the stacktrace. Also, have you declared the activity in the manifest?

Comment: The error is "adb refused a command". I'll look for a stack trace.

Comment: Stack trace has been included.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're calling `onSaveInstanceState()` twice. No bueno. You're also calling `setContentView()` twice. Also no bueno.

Second, why are you declaring a LinearLayout within your `onCreate()`? This is unnecessary. When you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_physics)` You now have a reference to that layout permanently.

Third, you're grabbing a reference to the EditText and then immediately trying to get the user's answer in `onCreate()`, which won't work because at this point, the user hasn't even seen the screen yet. You need some sort of "submit" button in the app that the user can click when they want to check their answer.

Try changing the code to this:

```
private EditText answer;
private Button submit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_physics);

    answer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userAnswer = answer.getText().toString();
            if(userAnswer.contains("remain"+"force"+"constant"+"velocity")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                }
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure you add a Button to your `xml` file and give it the id "submit".

Good luck.

Comment: I tried this but it isn't working. Your code is completely correct I need to check the log to see what's happening.

Comment: @EoinCoogan it could be the `contains(...)` function, I don't think it lets you concatenate terms like that......right now it looks like it is searching for "remainforceconstantvelocity". You might need to do `if useranswer.contains("remain") && useranswer.contains("force") && ....`

Comment: I have included the stack trace now.

Comment: @EoinCoogan that seems like the whole log for your entire device.....can you get one specific to your app?

Comment: The debug log is up

Answer (score 0):

You are not finding the view on correct layout.

Change

```
final EditText answer =  (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.answer);
```

to

```
final EditText answer =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is only an instantiation of the LinearLayout class:

```
 LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
```

So, if you request a subview as you did in this line:

```
final EditText answer =  (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.answer);
```

The app will crash because your "layout" is empty and doesn't contain the EditText that you requested!

Adding to this, if your main layout for the "MainActivity" is "activity_main.xml", you should only use:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Now, for the EditText, you're requesting the content of the EditText when the "MainActivity" is created which will always return an empty String (if you haven't set a default value for the EditText). You should give the time for the user to type something on the EditText box, then, you can retrieve the content of the EditText.

Just wanted to give you some tips that may help you in your future apps.
Use the code given by @privatestaticint and it should work fine :)